# View available network shares

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, blackberry-playbook

I would like to list all network shares but have no idea where to even begin my search, I assume that it has something to do with `Samba` etc., but really some guidance would be very useful.

I will be using Adobe AIR 2.5 - so I assume I have access to that sort of information, though I will be using the PlayBook from BlackBerry to access the network which has a full AIR implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network protocols like these are kind of out of the scope of Air.  You could try to look into the Socket class and try to implement your own Network discovery protocol, but it would be extremely difficult to achieve the same kind of functionality as smb.

Comment: I imagine one doesn't need to replicate all of smb - just the discovery portion. Then you could access the files as you would anything else as unc paths are usable in AIR?

Comment: I would imagine so, but don't quote me on that since I've never tried.  Maybe there is a library out there that already done the discovery.  Just search for it.

Comment: I've been looking but cannot find one pre-built, not quite sure how to proceed - I imagine something like nmap for shell would be perfect. At the moment I expect I'll have to build one from scratch but not sure on next step.

Comment: You could try to [extend Air functionality through Java}(http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/), but I'm not sure if this will work.  Worth a look into.  Other than that, I would start reading up on network discovery specs.

Comment: Not possible with Flash sockets, because they require special "socket policy file" response right after connection has been established.

Comment: @Alexander, not as far as I know.  For XML sockets yes, not for normal sockets.  I create an IRC client using sockets and it didn't need a policy file; same with the assql project.